# How would I get everything before a : in a string Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am looking for a way to get all of the letters in a string before a : but I have no idea on where to start. Would I use regex? If so how?

```
string = "Username: How are you today?"
```

Can someone show me a example on what I could do?

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Just use the `split` function. It returns a list, so you can keep the first element:

```
>>> s1.split(':')
['Username', ' How are you today?']
>>> s1.split(':')[0]
'Username'
```

Comment: Either *limit* the split, or in this case - use `s1.partition(':')[0]`

Comment: Thank you this was very useful and informative. Plus it wa s a big help thanks!

Comment: Don't use split, since it's processing all the ':' and creates a full array, not good for longer strings.  See @Hackaholic's approach to use an index.  Just that one is also recommending a regex which is clearly not as effective.  Also there has to be a python option to do the standard operation of .substringBefore() which is index based.  And also variations like .substringBeforeLast(), etc should be there for convenience(code should not be repeated).
Noticed the point about partition - yes, less processing after the ':', but still returns <class 'tuple'>: ('1', ':', '2:3') rather than '1'.

Comment: I think it's good unless you want to do this in loop over large strings that potentially have many `:` :) At least because it does have overhead of creating lists and it always process complete string ..  I think `index` with `try/catch` more efficient

Answer (score 110):

Using `index`:

```
>>> string = "Username: How are you today?"
>>> string[:string.index(":")]
'Username'
```

The index will give you the position of `:` in string, then you can slice it.

If you want to use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match("(.*?):",string).group()
'Username'
```

`match` matches from the start of the string.

you can also use `itertools.takewhile`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> "".join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!=":", string))
'Username'
```

Comment: This method ( string[:string.index(":")]) is probably cleaner than the split

Comment: For speed don't use regex - use the first index option mentioned here.  Regex is clearly not as effective.  Also there has to be a python option to do the standard operation of .substringBefore() which is index based.  And also variations like .substringBeforeLast(), etc should be there for convenience(code should not be repeated).
Suggest to update this answer to explain why the index works better and then why this should used over other approaches including over the one voted higher now in fredtantini's response.

Comment: If it's not present, index will fail.

Comment: Here in regex: re.match("(.*?):",string).group()    why do we need a '?' shouldn't this do 
 re.match("(.*):",string).group()

Comment: Shouldn't it be `re.match("(.*?):",string).group(1)` (probably needs some check if there is no colon)? `re.match("(.*?):",string).group()` seems to still include the colon.

Comment: `index()` won't work if there are multiple `':'`

Comment: To exclude the colon, you can use a lookahead like `re.match(".*?(?=:)", string).group()`.

Answer (score 29):

You don't need `regex` for this

```
>>> s = "Username: How are you today?"
```

You can use the `split` method to split the string on the `':'` character

```
>>> s.split(':')
['Username', ' How are you today?']
```

And slice out element `[0]` to get the first part of the string

```
>>> s.split(':')[0]
'Username'
```

Answer (score 21):

I have benchmarked these various technics under Python 3.9.13 (Jupyter Notebook).

#### TLDR

- When I know that `c` is in `s`, I would use **partition** for small strings and **index** for long strings.
- Otherwise, **partition**.

#### Code

```py
import string, random, re

SYMBOLS = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
SIZE = 10

def create_test_set(string_length):
    for _ in range(SIZE):
        random_string = ''.join(random.choices(SYMBOLS, k=string_length))
        yield (random.choice(random_string), random_string)

for string_length in (2**4, 2**8, 2**16, 2**20):
    print("\nString length:", string_length)
    test_set = list(create_test_set(string_length))
    test_set_for_regex = [(re.compile(fr"(.*?){c}").match, s) for (c, s) in test_set]
    print("  regex (compiled):", end=" ")
    %timeit [re_match(s)[1] for (re_match, s) in test_set_for_regex]
    print("  partition:       ", end=" ")
    %timeit [s.partition(c)[0] for (c, s) in test_set]
    print("  index:           ", end=" ")
    %timeit [s[:s.index(c)] for (c, s) in test_set]
    print("  split (limited): ", end=" ")
    %timeit [s.split(c, 1)[0] for (c, s) in test_set]
    print("  split:           ", end=" ")
    %timeit [s.split(c)[0] for (c, s) in test_set]
    print("  regex:           ", end=" ")
    %timeit [re.match(fr"(.*?){c}", s)[1] for (c, s) in test_set]
```

#### Results (reformatted and sorted for readability)

```
String length: 16
  partition:        1.86 µs
  split:            2.08 µs
  split (limited):  2.08 µs
  index:            2.37 µs
  regex (compiled): 3.52 µs
  regex:            8.77 µs

String length: 256
  partition:         1.92 µs
  index:             2.27 µs
  split (limited):   2.32 µs
  split:             5.37 µs
  regex (compiled):  7.59 µs
  regex:            12.90 µs

String length: 65536
  index:              2.20 µs
  regex (compiled):   7.15 µs
  regex:             12.10 µs
  partition:         25.70 µs
  split (limited):   25.90 µs
  split:           1110.00 µs

String length: 1048576
  index:              2.34 µs
  regex (compiled):   9.13 µs
  regex:             14.30 µs
  partition:        543.00 µs
  split (limited):  587.00 µs
  split:                      (interrupted before completion)
```

Comment: why do you consider *index* unsafe?

Comment: `s.index(c)` raises a ValueError when `c` is not in `s`. So, I consider it as safe when I am sure that the string to be partitioned contains the separator, unsafe otherwise.

Comment: For index, c is in s, so it is not unsafe and still fastest.

Comment: To exclude `c` from the result of the regex approach, you can use `re_match(s).group(1)` rather than `re_match(s).group()`. Alternatively, you can change the regex to use a lookahead like `re.compile(rf".*?(?={c})")`.

Comment: Oops, bug! Because `test_set_for_regex` is a generator, it gets emptied after the first iteration of `timeit`, and the following iterations don't do anything. If you make it a `list`, you should see the regex approach is ~1000 times slower than previously thought.

Comment: Also, you define `test_set = list(create_test_set(16))` ignoring `string_length`. In fact, the non-limited `split()` gets a lot slower when `string_length` increases. I get around 13 ms per loop with a `string_length` of `2**16`. I was not patient enough to wait for `2**32` to complete (that's a 4 GB string!).

Comment: @JosephMarinier You're right. I guess this is the sad result of exploring under a Jupyter Notebook and not relaunching the kernel before posting on SO... Anyway, it should be more legible and more correct now. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

[partition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) may be better then split() for this purpose as it has the better predicable results for situations you have no delimiter or more delimiters.

Comment: Both `partition` and `split` will work transparently with an empty string or no delimiters. It is worth noting that `word[:word.index(':')]` will pop  in both of these cases.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this using RegEx, you can use the Negative Lookahead/Negative Lookbehind approach.

For example, the code below for Python:

```
import re
string = "Username: How are you today?"
regex='(\S*)[:]'

data=re.findall(regex, string)
print(data)
```