# How do I use a regular expression to put the beginning of a string, preceding some user-specified character, into a group?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387415/how-would-i-get-everything-before-a-in-a-string-python/27387468), but I do not want a python specific solution. It should work in JavaScript, and any other mainstream language. It must be a regular expression.

Suppose that the delimiter was "`!`"

The table below shows the desired behavior for a few sample inputs

```
+------------------------+--------+
|         INPUT          | OUTPUT |
+------------------------+--------+
| "aaaa!bbbb"            | "aaaa" |
| "aaaa"                 | "aaaa" |
| "aaaa!bbbb!ccccc!dddd" | "aaaa" |
| "aaaa!"                | "aaaa" |
| "!aaaaa"               | ""     |
+------------------------+--------+
```

I tried the following to no avail:

"`^[^!]*$(!)`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `(!)` at the end. Just use `^([^!]*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capturing group for the part up to (but not including) `!` and replace the match with the first group:

```
^([^!]+)($|!.*$)
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/0h6yGl/1)

Comment: You can just use `.*` in the second group, there's no need for the details.

Comment: But the question never said anything about needing to capture the rest of the string.

Comment: This won't work for the last example in the table. `+` should be `*` to allow for an empty string before `!`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't' need to capture the test of the string, only the beginning up until the delimiter.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Isn't that what I said?