# Find string/float with Metacharacter with Regex in String (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem to find a string/float inside a string after serveral metacharacters with Python. I watched videos and read a lot of explanations, but for my special case I didn't find a solution, maybe you can help. I have a string with backslashs and asterisk and I want JUST the float after the string "*Score*" - how can I get it?

```
text = str("texttexttext\n*Score* 2,567 texttexttext")
y = re.findall("\\n*Score*(.+)", text)
print(y)

Output: ['* 2,567 texttexttext']
# I want JUST the Output "2,567"
```

Other Question: How can I get JUST the text before "\n*Score*"?

```
z = re.findall("^(.+)\\n*Score*", text)
print(z)
#no Output
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Why `text = str("texttexttext\n*Score* 2,567 texttexttext")` and not `text = "texttexttext\n*Score* 2,567 texttexttext"`? Anyway, the solution is known and simple: `re.findall(r"Score\D*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)", text)` or `re.findall(r"Score\D*(\d[\d,]*)", text)`

Comment: And for JUST the text before "\nScore"?
I'am sorry for being not such a good programmer to find this simple solution. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: Why regex at all? Use `text[:text.index("\\n*Score*")]`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387415/how-would-i-get-everything-before-a-in-a-string-python/27387468).

Comment: so this question is showed as duplicate, should I delete it now? I got a bad rating and can't ask questions anymore.

Comment: I suggest you keep the question, it is not bad.

Comment: wow I don't know what happened, I did just some small changes in my question above, but now I can ask questions again! thank you!